# Directly prove that power series are continuous within the radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let a power series have the radius of convergence $R$

We already know that the power series are uniformly convergent within $[-R+\varepsilon, R - \varepsilon]$, hence they are continuous on $(-R,R)$.

But is there a way to prove this directly, without the "uniform limit of continuous functions" theorem?

Motivation: we may encounter sequences of functions which are continuous and not uniformly convergent.

My try:

$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n y^n \right\rvert \le \left\lvert \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n x^n \right\rvert + \left\lvert\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n y^n \right\rvert + \left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x^n - \sum_{n=1}^N a_n y^n \right\rvert $$

But trying to set $N$ so that the first two moduli are small, we have to fix $x,y$ and trying to set the $\delta$ for the third modulus, we have to fix $N$. So this isn't valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|x^n - y^n| = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + \ldots + y^{n-1}| < n |x - y| r^{n-1}$ where $|x|,|y| < r$.  Note that $\sum_n n |a_n| r_1^{n-1}$ converges if $0 < r_1 < r_2 < R$ and $\sum_n |a_n| r_2^n$ converges.

Comment: but we don't know anything about the absolute convergence for $x=R$

Comment: Sorry, will edit.